# Matrix Factorization with SGD gets na results

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to implement MF with SGD to my sample data following thru https://nbviewer.org/github/albertauyeung/matrix-factorization-in-python/blob/master/mf.ipynb.

And, it's hard to figure out why the function returns na for RMSE only when I enter bigger numbers in the matrix. In the link, it uses a matrix with relatively small numbers and works fine. But only when I enter bigger numbers, for instance:

```
R = np.array([[12.,  0., 18., 15., 12.],
       [30., 40.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [40.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [22., 30., 35., 20., 30.],
       [40., 40., 38., 30., 38.],
       [30., 30., 30., 38., 30.]])
```

the prediction gets to inf., therefore returning NA for RMSE. It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me understand what to correct and how it works.

Comment: gradient descent is not invariant under scaling, and using bigger numbers will be directly equivalent to using a larger step size, which may result in nonconvergence. Try scaling your step size inversely to the scaling of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you John! I normalized the input values and figured it out!